# Localstorage issue with ios7

Tags: html, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am loading data from an array immediately on the apps startup. For some reason the local storage line that typically works when i test it in the simulator disables all of my javascript. I have this line right after I defined the array itself.

```
    uniqueIDarray = JSON.parse(localStorage.uniqueIDarray);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
uniqueIDarray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('uniqueIDarray'));
```